# Parsing through dataset

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, parsing

Using the Wordpress function `wp_load_alloptions()` I get a large array with all my sites option data. I selected a single portion of it that I need to globally get data from.

```
$all_options = wp_load_alloptions();
$my_options = array();
foreach( $all_options as $name => $value ) {
   if(stristr($name, 'options')) $my_options[$name] = $value;
}

echo '<pre>';
   print_r($my_options['sl_options_options']);
echo '</pre>';
```

This returns:

```
s:15:"popup_form_text";s:0:"";s:14:"popup_form_URL";s:124:"url";s:15:"popup_form_open";s:2:"14";s:16:"popup_form_close";s:2:"23";s:15:"evergage_toggle";s:2:"On";s:12:"optim_toggle";s:2:"On";s:13:"soasta_toggle";s:3:"Off";}
```

Is there a way I can parse through this data set to break out each individual part. Example of individual parts that go together:

```
s:12:"optim_toggle";s:2:"On";
```

Comment: This is a serialized array. It should start with `a:some_number:{...` you should be able to unserialize it an extract whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `unserialize` I was able to get the data to print out like I wanted.

Serialized Array:

```
s:15:"popup_form_text";s:0:"";s:14:"popup_form_URL";s:124:"url";s:15:"popup_form_open";s:2:"14";s:16:"popup_form_close";s:2:"23";s:15:"evergage_toggle";s:2:"On";s:12:"optim_toggle";s:2:"On";s:13:"soasta_toggle";s:3:"Off";}
```

using `unserialize`:

```
$unserialized_array = unserialize(s:15:"popup_form_text";s:0:"";s:14:"popup_form_URL";s:124:"url";s:15:"popup_form_open";s:2:"14";s:16:"popup_form_close";s:2:"23";s:15:"evergage_toggle";s:2:"On";s:12:"optim_toggle";s:2:"On";s:13:"soasta_toggle";s:3:"Off";});
```

Display the new array:

```
print_r(unserialize($unserialized_array));
```

Array now displays as:

```
Array(
   [popup_form_toggle] => On
   [popup_form_postids] => 51819, 36057, 36061, 36044, 44375, 36073, 48713, 17, 34612, 15908, 51054, 41102, 894
   [popup_form_text] => 
   [popup_form_URL] => https://home-c8.incontact.com/inContact/ChatClient/ChatClientPatron.aspx?poc=5ca78194-54ab-4833-8685-934a9d0305cc&bu=4594385
   [popup_form_open] => 14
   [popup_form_close] => 23
   [evergage_toggle] => On
   [optim_toggle] => On
   [soasta_toggle] => Off
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this ? :

```
preg_split('/;|,/', 's:15:"popup_form_text";s:0:"";s:14:"popup_form_URL";s:124:"url";s:15:"popup_form_open";s:2:"14";s:16:"popup_form_close";s:2:"23";s:15:"evergage_toggle";s:2:"On";s:12:"optim_toggle";s:2:"On";s:13:"soasta_toggle";s:3:"Off";}');
```

Output :

```
array(15) {
  [0] =>
  string(22) "s:15:"popup_form_text""
  [1] =>
  string(6) "s:0:"""
  [2] =>
  string(21) "s:14:"popup_form_URL""
  [3] =>
  string(11) "s:124:"url""
  [4] =>
  string(22) "s:15:"popup_form_open""
  [5] =>
  string(8) "s:2:"14""
  [6] =>
  string(23) "s:16:"popup_form_close""
  [7] =>
  string(8) "s:2:"23""
  [8] =>
  string(22) "s:15:"evergage_toggle""
  [9] =>
  string(8) "s:2:"On""
  [10] =>
  string(19) "s:12:"optim_toggle""
  [11] =>
  string(8) "s:2:"On""
  [12] =>
  string(20) "s:13:"soasta_toggle""
  [13] =>
  string(9) "s:3:"Off""
  [14] =>
  string(1) "}"
}
```

You can optimize it easily.

Comment: This set me on the right path! I actually used unserialize and got it to print out like I wanted. Will show results below!

Comment: preg_split is really usefull when you have redundant string !